# How to size multiple images in Word 2011 via macro

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, evernote

I am importing screen shots from an Evernote file, into Word 2011 (Mac OS X). They look fine in Evernote, but are huge (20") in Word 2011. I need to quickly shrink them to 4" wide, and center them.

Can I write a macro to do that? I can 'record' a macro, but it only does the centering, not the size change.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are supposed to be able to do something like

```
    objInlineShape.ScaleHeight
    objInlineShape.ScaleWidth
```

But I've never gotten it to work from a macro.